# Device to stream video from NAS (SMB network share) to TV?

Tags: networking, television, set-top-box

I have lots of video files stored on my network-attached drive.

All the computers in my network can access this drive and the videos on it. Currently this is achieved through Samba (each folder on the drive is made available to the network as an SMB share).

How can I get my TV to access and play these videos?

I am hoping there exists some device which I can plug in to an ethernet socket, and via an HDMI cable to my TV, which will let me browse the network share and then just play a video, directly from the TV. Ideally it will be able to play most video files with all kinds of different codecs. (But for the most part they are H264 encoded files.)

Comment: https://www.broadbandbuyer.com/features/2219-the-easy-way-to-stream-from-a-synology-nas-to-a-smart-tv

Comment: I've been using an XBox One with the Kodi app for accessing SMB shares over my local network.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think a TV will ever be able to read from an SMB share, plus I don't believe there's a little magical device that enables such feature.

BUT! You might want to install Plex, Emby, or Kodi on your NAS and then download the corresponding app on your TV.

Once everything's set up, you should be able to browse all your media on your Television too.

Of course my advice is to keep those SMB shares active, so you can still access your media through your other computers.

Hope this helps!